# processing audio samples while recording in matlab

Tags: matlab, audio, real-time

I'm doing an audio processing project. I have to record audio from a microphone and have to process those samples real time. While the recording process is carried out, I must process the samples and play them back. I am using the code below to record my audio.

```
% Setting parameters
Fs = 44100;
nbits = 16;
dev_id = getfield(getfield(audiodevinfo, 'input'), 'ID');

% Creating the audiorecorder object
arec = audiorecorder(Fs, nbits, 2, dev_id);
display('Start speaking.');
recordblocking(arec, 15.0);
display('End of Recording.');

data = getaudiodata(arec);
display(data);
soundsc(data, Fs);
plot(data);
wavwrite(data,Fs,nbits,'changed.wav');
```

Can real time processing can be done? Can someone please give me an idea?

Comment: This code records all of the audio as a single segment, then processes the recorded audio.  What are you trying to accomplish?  Judging from your problem description, your code is doing what you want it to do.

Answer (score 0):

Real time processing usually means that you receive a streaming block of data, process it, and pass it to the output without having any gaps or stops in the stream. As you might have discovered, that is not what is happening with your code above.

Unfortunately standard Matlab does not not support real time processing of signals, but if you look into the DSP Systems Toolbox addon, you'll find the necessary functionality, along with some examples.

Another option is to implement a the real time processing through a MEX interface instead.